# Why does Spring Web throw a 415 error code response on a GET request?

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm converting a Spring application from a much older version of Spring to the current version.  I've hit a number of issues I've had to address.  Here's one I don't understand how to go about fixing, and wonder why I have to.  This one seems like a bug to me...

I've got a series of REST apis, each of which consists of mixtures of GET and POST requests.  In the case of POST request bodies, and in all cases for response bodies, I return JSON.  Therefore, it seems that I can globally define my return types for an entire API module as so:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/v1", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public class ApiService_Account extends ApiServiceBase {
    ...
```

My problem is that I get a 415 response for GET requests, with the message "Content type '' is not supported".  But GET requests generally Have No Content, and therefore Have No Content Type. Why is the code complaining about the type of non-existing content in a case where no content is expected?

Here's my definition of one such endpoint, in case it matters:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/accounts")
@ResponseBody
public void getAccounts(...
```

I don't see it making sense to require a Content-Type header (and probably a JSON type specifically) in a GET request.  I'd rather not have to define my payload types for every endpoint definition.

What's the best course here?  Am I missing something?  Is this a bug?  Is there a way to specify the 'consumes' property for just all POST requests?

UPDATE: I can see that Spring is just being very literal here, and that's maybe the end of it.  I'm telling it that all my endpoints should be expecting JSON, and it's just following through on that.  Maybe it doesn't make sense for it to make an exception for GET requests, even though GETs shouldn't have bodies.  So maybe this is a "feature".  Still, I'd like to know how to work around it so I don't have to specify a "consumes" on every one of my endpoints.  I suppose I could put my POSTs in one class, and my GETs in another.  Yuck.

PS: If I remove the 'consumes' param from the first annotation, the problem goes away.  I haven't yet explored if that breaks my POST methods that do expect JSON bodies.

Answer (score 0):

Defining `@RequestMapping(consumes = "application/json")` on the class level enforces the usage of the `Content-Type` header for all requests made to one of the endpoints defined in this class. Resulting in a 415 response when the header is left out.

Spring is not smart enough to figure out that `Content-Type` on a GET request does not make sense.

AFAIK there is no easy way to circumvent this. The easiest solution would be:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/v1", produces = "application/json")
public class ApiService_Account extends ApiServiceBase {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/accounts")
    @ResponseBody
    public void getAccounts(...

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/accounts", consumes = "application/json")
    public void saveAccount(@RequestBody Account account...
```

This way you would need to define `consumes` on `RequestMapping` endpoint which really consume content.